# Back button in fragment Android-Related

Tags: android, fragment

I have one fragment in which a listview is created. When the list is clicked the same list is refreshed and its child elements are loaded on the same. Could anyone please tell me how to enable the backbutton in android to get the parent list?

Comment: Please explain in brief and proper

Comment: Add an interface in your fragment which your activity can call for onBackPressed event, on that event (let's call it OnBackPressedListener.onBackPressed()) do like this onBackPressed(){if(adapter.getIsShowingChild()){adapter.replaceItems(parentList);}}. You can add your code to maintain state of what is being shown.

Comment: is there any way to link backbutton in fragment without creating an interface???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the method `onResume()`

```
@Override
public void onResume() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override your activity's onBackPressed() and get the fragment instance by FragmentManager, and do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take callback from onBackPressed of Activity to Fragment and check in Fragment if there is child elements open or not.

In Activiity

```
public void onBackPressed()
{
  if(!fragment.onBackPressed())//onBackPressed in fragment is your own function
  {
    super.onBackPressed();
  }
}
```

In Fragment

```
public boolean onBackPressed() //your custom onBackPressed not overrided
{
  if(childListOpen)
  {
    //close the child list
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
   // whatever to do in back pressed of list
    return false;
  }   
}
```

Comment: How can i remove the  last  key from hashmap

Comment: what do you mean by **last key** ?  if this is map.keyset() last key then get last key from keyset and remove by map.remove(key)

Comment: lastkey means the key that finally entered

Comment: for that use **LinkedHashMap** in which there is retain insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

For your simplicity, Define one static variable in your activity that track the which fragment is currently visible, like

`public static fragIndex = 0;`

then in your fragment oncreateView before returning view set it accordingly to fragments. like in list view fragment

`MainActivity.fragIndex = 0;`

and for detailed fragment

`MainActivity.fragIndex = 1;`

now on your activities onbackpressed method do like

```html
if(fragIndex == 0){
//whatever you want to do.
}else if(fragIndex == 1){
// change the fragment back to list view
}
```

Comment: thats just working when a single fragment is shown. On Tablets thats not working with some extra logic.